# d3 scale in typescript filling space on last x-axis item?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

i have this xscale which works fine in js but not in ts:

```
 const xScale = scaleTime()
        .domain([xMinDate, xMaxDate])
        .range([0, width]);
```

the last item xScale  value in js is: 797.0688968538431 but on ts, the last item is 800 equal to the width above automatically? the result is below
[image: result]

Comment: Using TS should not change the behavior of how the d3 scales work. Could you post both the working JS and problem TS sections?

Comment: i am certain both have same values on logs, but xScale on typescript last index is the only difference